# Wrap a primitive returned from a Spring controller into json

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

For now, I am using something like this:

```
@RequestBody
@RequestMapping("whatever")
public ObjectWrapper<Integer> foo() {
    return new ObjectWrapper<>(42);
}
```

What I would like to do is to rewrite the method in the following way

```
@RequestBody
@RequestMapping("whatever")
public int foo() {
    return 42;
}
```

and get 42 (or any other primitive) wrapped into ObjectWrapper before it gets serialized (by Jackson) and gets written into response. I wonder if it is actually possible and, if so, how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As I have misunderstood your question, I updated my answer:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();
        super.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }
}
```

Add to default message converter:

```
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>  
    </mvc:message-converters>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.mysite.CustomObjectMapper" />
```

However this might not produce the output you desired.

Best thing is to write your own serializer and use it with your custom object mapper and wrap primitives in your serializer.

Here is something related: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/34

Comment: I have misunderstood your question at first and updated my answer.